# How to write Inner Query Programatically to fetch latest record based on condition

Tags: sql-server, jpa, spring-data-jpa, criteria

My use case is to find latest records( by date) based on some filter criteria from a SQL table.I had constructed the SQL query and ran it through the SQL IDE and it is working fine. I am using MS Sql Serve as my database.

But when i am trying to convert this query programatically using Spring-Data JPA/Criteria, **i am not getting how to achieve that.**

**Here is my query to find latest record based on src_cc, src_nbr and isvariableWeight: -**

```
    SELECT *
    FROM
    dcfin_test Tab1
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
            ibd_doc_nbr,
            ibd_doc_line_nbr,
            MAX(create_ts) AS max_Ts
        FROM
            dcfin_test
        WHERE
            src_cc = 'US'
            AND src_nbr = 6938
            AND isvariableWeight = 'Y'
        GROUP BY
            ibd_doc_nbr,
            ibd_doc_line_nbr) Tab2 ON Tab1.ibd_doc_nbr = Tab2.ibd_doc_nbr
    AND Tab1.ibd_doc_line_nbr = Tab2.ibd_doc_line_nbr
    AND Tab1.create_ts = Tab2.max_Ts;
```

Here src_cc, src_nbr and isVaribaleWeight will be passed during runtime programatically. Above is shown for example purpose.

Here is my Entity Model looks like (other unwanted column has been removed) :-

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.time.Instant;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;


@Entity
@Table(name = "dcfin_test")
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class WeightedAlertEntity {

@Id
@Column(name = "weightedAlertId")
private String weightedAlertId;

@Column(name = "src_cc")
private String sourceCC;

@Column(name = "src_nbr")
private int sourceNbr;

@Column(name = "isVaribaleWeight")
private String isVaribaleWeight;

@Column(name = "ibd_doc_nbr")
private String inboundDocNbr;

@Column(name = "ibd_doc_line_nbr")
private String inboundDocNbrLineNbr;

@Column(name = "item_nbr")
private String itemNbr;


@Column(name = "wac_percent_change")
private BigDecimal percentWacChange;

@Column(name = "waw_percent_change")
private BigDecimal percentWawChange;

@Column(name = "created_by")
private String createdBy;

@Column(name = "create_ts")
private Instant createTs;
```

}

I tried doing it using native Query in spring Data JPA and it looks like as follows :-

```
@Repository
public interface WeightedAlertEntityDao
extends JpaRepository<WeightedAlertEntity, String> {

@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM dcfin_weighted_alert_data Tab1 "
        + "INNER JOIN ("
        + "SELECT ibd_doc_nbr,ibd_doc_line_nbr,MAX(create_ts) AS max_Ts FROM dcfin_weighted_alert_data"
        + " WHERE src_cc = ?1 AND src_nbr = ?2 AND weight_format_type = ?3 "
        + "GROUP BY ibd_doc_nbr, ibd_doc_line_nbr) Tab2 "
        + "ON Tab1.ibd_doc_nbr = Tab2.ibd_doc_nbr "
        + "AND Tab1.ibd_doc_line_nbr = Tab2.ibd_doc_line_nbr "
        + "AND Tab1.create_ts = Tab2.max_Ts", nativeQuery = true)
public List<WeightedAlertEntity> getAlertEntityBasedOnFilterCondition(
    String sourceCC, Integer srcNbr, String weightFormatType);
```

}

And when i called above method from my service layer as below :-

```
List<WeightedAlertEntity> alertEntityBasedOnFilterCondition = weightedAlertDao.getAlertEntityBasedOnFilterCondition(
        header.getFacilityCountryCode(),Integer.parseInt(header.getFacilityNum()),
        weightFormatType);
```

**Update on my Question :-**

I have checked it thoroughly and found out that there was a mistake which leads to invalid column name as i used Tab2.create_ts in place of Tab2.max_Ts. Now i am able to get the results.

I need pagination support too as part of this query i.e. if user enters pageNum = 1 and pagesize = 10, i should be able to return 10 results if records are more.
and when user enters pageNum = 2, pageSize = 10, i should return next 10 records.

**Can someone look into it and guide me how to achieve this using Spring Data Jpa / Criteria ?**

Comment: If you just want the `MAX` value for `modified_ts`, why not just use a windowed `MAX` in the outer query? There's no need for a subquery here.

Comment: I am looking for complete row data (it would be list of records) not only modfied_ts. Modified_ts is a column which is used to find the most recent record.

Comment: There is a complex query, but you haven't shown how you have mapped anything in JPA. What does your model look like, what have you tried, what results are you looking to use in your application? Pagination comes after you've worked out everything else - otherwise, just use a native SQL query and get the raw data.

Comment: @Chris i have edited the question based on what i have tried till now.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the solution to "Top N Items Per Group". Use this phrase in your favorite search engine and several methods of solving the problem will appear. The ones I'd opt for are

- Window Functions
- `CROSS APPLY` join with subquery.

Comment: As you could see , i have already wrote the SQL to find TOP n items based on condition. I am basically looking to convert to programatically using Spring Data JPA/ native Quert/Criteria.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked it thoroughly and found out that there was a mistake which leads to invalid column name (create_ts) as i used Tab2.create_ts in place of Tab2.max_Ts from inner Query. Now i am able to get the results.

Now when i tried to do pagination using Pageable like below :-

```
            Page<WeightedAlertEntity> alertEntityBasedOnFilterCondition = weightedAlertDao.getAlertEntityBasedOnFilterCondition(
                header.getFacilityCountryCode(),
                Integer.parseInt(header.getFacilityNum()),
                weightFormatType, PageRequest.of(0, 10));
```

this is my repository class looks like :-

```
@Repository
public interface WeightedAlertEntityDao
extends JpaRepository<WeightedAlertEntity, String> {

@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM dcfin_weighted_alert_data as Tab1 "
        + "INNER JOIN ("
        + "SELECT Tab3.ibd_doc_nbr,Tab3.ibd_doc_line_nbr,MAX(Tab3.create_ts) AS max_Ts FROM dcfin_weighted_alert_data as Tab3"
        + " WHERE Tab3.src_cc = ?1 AND Tab3.src_nbr = ?2 AND Tab3.weight_format_type = ?3 "
        + "GROUP BY Tab3.ibd_doc_nbr, Tab3.ibd_doc_line_nbr) as Tab2 "
        + "ON Tab1.ibd_doc_nbr = Tab2.ibd_doc_nbr "
        + "AND Tab1.ibd_doc_line_nbr = Tab2.ibd_doc_line_nbr "
        + "AND Tab1.create_ts = Tab2.max_Ts", nativeQuery = true)
public Page<WeightedAlertEntity> getAlertEntityBasedOnFilterCondition(
    String sourceCC, Integer srcNbr, String weightFormatType, Pageable pageable);
```

}

I am getting this error:- **The column 'ibd_doc_nbr' was specified multiple times for 'inner_query'.**

Same query when i try using SQL IDE, it is working fine. Can someone help me where i am doing wrong.